# Ordered Display of Array of Objects Based on Creation Date in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am trying to display the list of items that i am getting response from my `get` request response. So How do I sort on the basis of created date `Mon, 18 Oct 2021 22:46:50 GMT`     is the date format I am displaying to my table.
My code goes:

```
const display = todoList
.sort((a, b) => {
  return (
    new Date(a.createdAt).toUTCString() -
    new Date(b.createdAt).toUTCString()
  );
})
.map((item) => (
  <tr key={item.id}>
    <td>{item.title}</td>
    <td>{new Date(item.CreatedAt).toUTCString()}</td>

    <td>
      <button onClick={() => Update(item.id)} className="btn btn-success">
        Update
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onClick={() => remove(item.id)} className="btn btn-Danger">
        Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
));
```

response
[image: response picture]

[image: Json response]

Comment: And the actual problem is? Use `.sort()` before `.map()` and job done.

Comment: @Andreas I tried that it doesn't work. the acutal problem is it is not sorting on the basis of created date instead it is displaying in order of id.

Comment: Then show us that approach, and explain what _"doesn't work"_ actually means -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), _""It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question"_

Comment: Have a look at the [Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#examples)

Comment: Subtracting two strings doesn't produce any output in JavaScript.  You can't use `string1 - string2` as a comparator function.  Take a look at my answer where I thresh this out a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the MDN Webdocs for [**`sort()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  Specifically, look at their example, it is returning `0`, `-1`, or `1`, and only these values.  Your function, on the other hand, returns a UTC date (minus) another UTC date.  What you need is not `"string1 - string2"`, but `"if string1 > string2 return 1, else"`, etc...

Change your sort to use `-1` or `1`, and string `>` comparisons instead of string `-` comparisons, like below, and it'll sort correctly...

```js
todoList = [
 {'createdAt':'2000-01-01 12:00:00'},
 {'createdAt':'2000-01-01 10:00:00'},
];

todoList.sort((a, b) => {
  if(new Date(a.createdAt) > new Date(b.createdAt)) {
   return 1;
  }
  return -1;
});

console.log(todoList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort will not work like that. You can try something like this. I have no clue how your toDoList array looks, but here's a guess. And then you map.

```
toDoList.sort((a,b)=> {
  return new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt);
});
```

Comment: I have added my response. it is showing recent submitted data at last instead of first.

Comment: you can adjust the sort a.createdAt - b.createdAt.

Comment: I have updated code. Am i doing any wrong while sorting because it shows no changes.

Comment: can you share a sample of your toDoList in the code? I can't check anything since I don't know how it looks

Comment: I have updated to my question. Json resposne

Comment: pls share actual code. don't post screenshots of code because those are not helpful